# Reading Csvs, adding a column, putting data into the new column and then saving csvs in python

Tags: python, csv

I currently have a folder with about 300 csv files in them. What I want to do is to read all the csv files within the folder.

The Csv files currently have two columns in them. I want to add a third column to each file.

In this third column I want there to be either a 1 or a 0 depending on whether the corresponding value is greater than or equal to or less than 64

So I have this code which does what I want to an individual file but I need help in how to iterate over all the files in the directory and do it for all of them

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

df['Above_64'] = ''

df.loc[df.value < 64, 'Above_64'] = '0'
df.loc[df.value >= 64, 'Above_64'] = '1'

df.to_csv('test2.csv')
```

Comment: Look into [file globbing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html), put a loop around your existing code and run it for each file the glob returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you started working on this and have code already that you are stuck on? That would help people give some specific help.

Generally, though, you can use the `glob` module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to help identify all files in a folder. You can do a for-loop in that folder to grab each file and perform the transformations on it.

If you do glob.glob(*filepath*) (with whatever wildcards), that will return a list of filepaths-as-strings that you can then loop (or iterate) through. So you can do something like

You can use `pandas` (https://pandas.pydata.org/) to pull the data from the csv into a "dataframe" in python, then pandas can add columns on whatever your criteria is, and then you re-save the file.

Then your for-loop goes into the next file, on and on to the end.

```py
files = glob.glob(filepath)
for file in files:
   df = pandas.read_csv(file) #makes a dataframe from the file contents
   df['new column'] = df[column_name] >= 64 #makes the new column a true/false based on the criteria. you can put whatever new column name in the quotes, but you need the old column name in the second-half
   df['new column'].replace([True,False],[1,0],inplace=True) #replace true/false with 1/0. inplace=True makes it change the column rather than return the info as a series
   df.to_csv(file) #save this new dataframe as the same file you read it from
```

Comment: So I have a list of all the filenames in the folder using glob. I'm not really sure where to start with the for-loop as this is something i've not really done before in python although i'm relatively familiar with them from matlab.

Comment: @LewisDorling, i added more info in the answer